# dispatch is not returnig promise i think?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I want to write a CRUD in react-redux, and have a problem with multiple dispatch. I think my dispatch is not returning a promise?

my error is "Uncaught TypeError: dispatch(...).then is not a function", on this line:

```
fetchPost: (id) => {
                dispatch(fetchPost(id))
                    .then((result) => ...
```

Action

```
export function fetchPost(id) {
    const request = axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/posts/details/${id}`);
    console.log(request);
    return {
        type: "FETCH_POST",
        payload: request
    }
}

export function fetchPostSuccess(post) {
    return{
        type: "FETCH_POST_SUCCESS",
        payload: post
    }
}

export function fetchPostError(error) {
    return{
        type: "FETCH_POST_ERROR",
        payload: error
    }
}
```

Reducer

```
case "FETCH_POST":
    return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,  
        activePost: state.activePost
    }
case "FETCH_POST_SUCCESS":
    return {
        ...state,
        activePost: action.payload
    }
case "FETCH_POST_ERROR":
    return {
        ...state,
        activePost: []            
    }
```

Component

```
class Details extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchPost(this.props.detail_id.id);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Details page
                <ul>
                    <li >
                        {this.props.detail_id.id}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Container

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({ 
    posts: state.posts,
});


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {

        fetchPost: (id) => {
            dispatch(fetchPost(id))
                .then((result) => {
                    if (result.payload.response && result.payload.response.status !== 200){
                        dispatch(fetchPostError(result.payload.response.data));
                    } else {
                        dispatch(fetchPostSuccess(result.payload.data));
                    }
                })
        },
        resetMe: () => {
            console.log('reset me');
        }
    };
};

const GetDetails = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Details)
```

I just want to pick post from postlist and show details on enother page...Hope someone help me to fix this issue

Saga

```
export function* fetchProducts() {
    try {
        console.log('saga')
        const posts = yield call(api_fetchPost);
        console.log(posts);
        yield put({ type: "FETCH_SUCCESS", posts});
    } catch (e) {
        yield put({ type: "FETCH_FAILD", e});
        return;
    }
}

export function* watchFetchProducts() {
    yield takeEvery("FETCH_POSTS", fetchProducts)
}
```

Comment: `fetchPost(id)` is returning an action not promise. To work with async actions, I suggest, look into redux-thunk or redux-saga.

Comment: i am using redux saga to load a json file

Answer (score 0):

According to [the Redux documentation](https://redux.js.org/api-reference/store#dispatch-action), `dispatch()` returns the dispatched action, i.e. it's argument. The dispatched action is just a plain object which describes an action.

The promise is returned by [Axios'](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosgeturl-config) `get()` method which is just an alias for `axios()` method.

Both call of the asynchronous method and the promise resolving should be done in Redux action. There is [Redux Thunk middleware](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) to handle such asynchronous actions. With Thunk middleware, you may return a function from your action. The function takes single argument `dispatch`, which is Redux's `dispatch()` function which you can call from functions resolving a promise.

With Redux Thunk middleware, your action `fetchPost()` will take the following view:

```js
export function fetchPost(id) {
    return function(dispatch) {
        dispatch({type: 'FETCH_POST'})

        axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/posts/details/${id}`)
            .then(function(response) {
                if (response.status === 200){
                    dispatch({type: 'FETCH_POST_SUCCESS', payload: response.data})
                } else {
                    dispatch({type: 'FETCH_POST_ERROR', payload: respose.data})
                }
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                dispatch({type: 'FETCH_POST_ERROR', payload: error})
            })
    }
}
```

Your actions `fetchPostSuccess()` and `fetchPostError()` are unnecessary.

Comment: tnx for great explanation. i am using a redux saga to load a json file. What do you thing about using axios and saga? fetchPost() stayes a same?

Comment: @Qli I have no experience with `redux-saga`. Anyway `fetchPost()` must either resolve a promise returned by Axios' `get()` or save it somewhere to let it be resolved in other place.